# Unabe to Boot From Disk Drive

Tags: boot

I have built a new desktop computer. However I'm unable to boot from the disk (optical) drive in order to install the OS.

When I put the DVD containing the OS into the disk drive, it stalls for about 10-20 seconds then the system enters into the BIOS.

- disk drive: Lite-On Super AllWrite IHAS124-04-KIT 24X DVD+/-RW Dual Layer Burner
- Motherboard: ASUS H81M-PLUS mATX

The disk drive is set as the first boot option...

Comment: I had the same problem when I build my current desktop. A strange but working solution (at least for me) was to move the optical drive to a different SATA controller. When I connect it to the controller on the X58 chipset I can not boot from it, even if it is selected as first device. After moving it to one of the extra SATA controllers on the motherboard it works fine.  I never bother to find out why. Still, worth trying.

Comment: Will try that...

Comment: If it works and you find out how/what/why then I would love to know. I just never needed the optical drive anymore after XP got replaced.

Comment: I'm reusing the case from the old computer...

Comment: Good enough reason :) My case still has an old fashioned 3.5 inch 1.44MB (unconnected atm) and in the closet is a 5.25 inch drive. Both pale to the ancient system next to it with with two 360k drives (and only those).
http://i.stack.imgur.com/mDXo5.jpg

Comment: Go it working using a spare drive...

Comment: The Lite-On Optical drive is not being detected by your system , could be the SATA data or power cable , try this drive on another computer if it works , reset your BIOS to default settings or try to look for an upgrade.

Comment: @Suzana the BIOS shows it as "ATAPI iHAS124        E" including which SATA controller it is connected to.... pix forthcoming

Comment: @JCM Ok then , i can think of only these solutions : 1- Upgrading the the optical drive's firmware(Its has been useful for me once when installing Win 7 that didn't find my drive) ,2-Upgrading your BIOS's firmware  if there is one.3- try another CD/DVD disk , as sometimes they are burned too fast or too slow or with some burning options that aren't supported on new drives but works fine on older drives.

Comment: @Suzana I flashed the BIOS firmware to the latest version. As suggested elsewhere in this thread I tried different SATA controllers... finally I tried with old disk disk drive using a PATA/IDE/SATA adapter and that worked... so perhaps there are connectivity with new disk drive...

Comment: @JCM ,there seems to be someone who had the same issue and i think he solved it , you might wanna look at this question :[link](http://superuser.com/questions/817307/optical-drive-delaying-boot-substantially)

Comment: @Suzana  thanks.  Will take a look the link and will continuw to thinker with the machine until it works.

Comment: @Suzana as promised here is the picture: <http://imgur.com/12x9Qco>. The optical drive shows up as "ATAPI iHAS124    E"